# External API closing connection after some time

Tags: api, rest

I am using the .net framework for calling an external API that returns data in JSON format.
The case is something like this

1. the First call goes to API which returns around 3500 records.
2. For each record now I am making a new call to the same API with different parameters which returns 4-5 records
3. For each record returned in step 2, I am making another call to the same API with different parameters

Now till 2000 records, it works fine and is able to get data for each step.
After processing 200 records, the external API starting throwing exception
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

I tried running my console application many times but getting the same error every time.
I don't have access to the external API. I need to modify my code in order to get all data.

Answer (score 1):

After exploring many techniques, server was refusing requestes after few minutes.
So for 3500 records, I made 3500 tasks and waited for all of them to completed and then proceeded further.
This way I was wable to get the record for all the data without connection issue. I don't know if it is good solution but yes it worked.

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();    
for(int i=0; i<recordCount;i++){
    taskList.Add(new Task(()=>ProcesRecord());
}
Task.WaitForAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

If anyone one have better solution or idea, please suggest.